# Reduplication words

Tags: meaning, reduplication

What is the difference between 久々 and 久し振り? Is 久々 derived from the root of 久しい?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the difference would be minimal and to say otherwise would be nitpicking.

「久々{ひさびさ}」 could at times sound ***slightly*** more formal and emphatic than 「久{ひさ}し振{ぶ}り」.  For that reason, you would hear the latter more often in the informal daily conversations among us native speakers.

> " Is 久々 derived from the root of 久しい?"

Yes, certainly.  You know reduplication is a trademark of our language.